# mark the contours in matplotlib contourf by (x,y) indices and not levels?

Tags: matplotlib, contour

In my pcolor map, I want to mark contours , but for values which dont depend on the Z values of the pcolor ( specified by levels) but on the basis of specific (x,y) indices. How can i do this ?

Thanks in advance,
Jyotika

Comment: Can you show us what you have done?  You will get better responses if you ask for help with a _specific_ chunk of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you could do something like this to get a contour around a particular set of x and y indices:

```
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(10), np.arange(10))
z = np.zeros(x.shape)
z[(x<3) & (y>5)] = 1
plt.contour(x, y, z)
plt.show()
```

or if your question is that you want to base contour lines on z values at specific x,y locations:

```
V = [z[1,2], z[2,3], z[3,4]]
plt.contour(x, y, z, V)
```

Comment: Thank you ! Thats exactly what i needed. The first snippet of code, that is.